# External matlab optimization function (value) needs be called in Simulink

Tags: matlab, optimization, external

I have a simulink file, where I need to call a certain optimization function:

```
function u = MPC(r, x0, Thorizon, Q, W, cons)
R = [];
    for s=1:Thorizon+1
        R = vertcat(R, r);
    end


ops = sdpsettings('solver','quadprog','verbose',0);    
U = sdpvar(Thorizon+1,1);
cost = (R - (Q*U+W*x0))'*(R-(Q*U+W*x0))+U'*U;
optimize(cons,cost,ops);
u = value(U);
u = u(1);
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to implement this in Simulink.
I tried it with a matlab function block, but a couple of problems arise.
First of all, it returns some errors like

> Function 'eval' is not supported for code generation. Consider adding
>   coder.extrinsic('eval') at the top of the function to bypass code
>   generation.

or like

> Function 'sdpsettings.m' (#103.12741.12757), line 355, column 12:
>   "temporaryOptions" Launch diagnostic report.

It has (probably) to do with the fact that the optimizer (sdp) is an external function, one that is part of a seperately installed library.

The other possible issue, is one with the input arguments.
If I were to use a Matlab function block, there would be a problem with the cons argument, one that can take inequality forms, like

```
U<1
```

The function, does however, work in the Matlab environment itself.
But the output of this function, needs to be the input of a continuous non-linearm model present in simulink.

So my question is, 
are there any suggestions, to either: Make such function in Simulink work, like via a Matlab function block, or use the function in the matlab runtime environment itself, and send the output value repeatedly to the simulink model?